# Angular Material Table - Summary Row - Workaround (Material 2)

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material

I am working on angular project, in which we required to show total hours spent by employee on each project in tabular form.

We decided to use **angular material table** for that. We have already implemented filtering, pagination and sorting functionality in table. Now, we need to display total hours spent by employee at the bottom of table. this value will change as user apply filtering on table.
We need something like Jquery Datatable footer as in example given in below link :
[Jquery Datatable footer](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html)

My implementation of angular material data table is similar of example table given in following link :
[Angular Material Datatable Example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

According to this [Github Link](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7548), there is no such functionality in angular material table.

can anyone help me to find workaround for this?

Comment: If you want to show some summary on every page and every filter case, then its probably better to show outside of table, as a separate module, like you (and angular material team) did with filter input and pagination. Subscribe to all table changes and compute summary block appropriately

Comment: @VagrantAI , tnx for reply. i want to show summary on every filter. can you give example of how to subscribe for table changes? it will be helpful.

Comment: use Observable from connect() function of DataSource

Answer (score 3):

this is way how I sum all rows of (material) dataTable in Angular 5:

function in component:

```
  calculation() {
    let sum: number = 0;
    if (this.dataSource)
      for (let row of this.dataSource.data) {
        if (row.id != 0) sum += row.iznos;
      }
    return sum;
  }
```

line below table in html:

```
   {{ calculation() }}
```

Note: i compare row.id with 0 to exclude some (not saved) rows...

Comment: It works, but if I want to sum only the records of page using pagination ?

Comment: It's better to use a reduce

Comment: this is a nad solution, `calculation()` will be called each time angular runs change detection, which triggers very often.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else wondering about this. Material has included a directive on the dataSource called "filteredData".

I was able to implement it like this.

`doFilter(fitlervalue: string) {
this.dataSource.filter = fitlervalue.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
this.totalDuration = this.dataSource.filteredData.map(t => t.duration).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0)
}`

Bind the total row to the element. In my instance it is total duration.

```
<td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> {{totalDuration | number }} </td>
```

My input field looked like this:

`<input type="text" matInput (keyup)="doFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter past exercises">`

Just note you may want to set a function which calls under ngOnInit to see the initial values.

Answer (score 1):

Store `total hours` as a component's property and recalculate it each time it should be recalculated. For example when applying filtering.
And in your component's template add
`<tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>`
to tell angular table to show footer row. And as for the footer cell itself:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="hours">
    <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Hours </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
        Hours: {{ element.hours }}
    </td>
    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>
        Total hours: {{ totalHours }}
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Solution proposed by @Ivica Buljević will work, but `calculation()` function will be triggered each time user interacts with the page, which will introduce additional performance overhead, which, I suspect, is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using the Angular Material Table itself.
You can add a footer row and let the value be bind to some function call of your own to display the total value in that row.

Here's an example reference from the Angular Material Docs: https://stackblitz.com/angular/jxyeybxbayx?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-footer-example.ts